# google calendar dates format explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, google-calendar-api, freshdesk

I am trying to display google calendar on my website with the below Url

```
 <a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?
    action=TEMPLATE&
    text={{ticket.subject}}&
    dates=20170127T210000Z/20170127T220000Z&
    details=For+details,+link+here:+https://www.example.com/&
    location=Hyderabad,+Telangana,+India&sf=true&
    output=xml#eventpage_6" 
    target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to calender</a>
```

As you can observe I have hard coded the dates values as `dates=20170127T210000Z/20170127T220000Z`, but I couldn't able to understand the format

```
20170127T210000Z = 2017 01 27 but what is T210000Z?
```

Because I need to generate it dynamically with my ticket creation due date which was in the following

```
helpdesk_ticket.due_by = "2017-01-17T17:00:00-05:00"
```

Comment: T is separating the time part (hour in 24 hour furthest  then minutes then seconds, each two digits). The +/- afterwards is the time zone offset.

Answer (score 3):

It's the standard [Internet Date/Time Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) following the RFC3339 protocol.

> The following profile of ISO 8601 [ISO8601] dates SHOULD be used in
> new protocols on the Internet.  This is specified using the syntax
> description notation defined in [ABNF].
>
> ```
> date-time       = full-date "T" full-time
> time-offset     = "Z" / time-numoffset
> ```

You can see those date properties in [Calendar Events properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource).
To convert a date into RFC339 date-time formats in JS, use [.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```
var today = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(today.toISOString()); // Returns 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the original format from google calendar dates:

```
dates=20170127T210000Z/20170127T220000Z
```

To explain i will convert this to:

```
format='Ymd\\THi00\\Z+UTCTIME'
```

The above format it means:

```
Y = years
m = month
d = day
T = make it as default dont change this. (Indicates the start of the time portion of the date time)
H = hours
i = minutes
00 = make it as default dont change this.
Z = make it as defaut dont change this. (Indicates the time zone is UTC)
+UTCTIME = your utc zone
```

Here an example :

```
20220523T100000Z+07:00
```

This is the result of an example:

```
23 May 2022, 10.00am base on my utc in indonesia use +07:00
```